# Why do we use the top left corner as the origin in image processing?

Tags: image-processing

Why do we do this in image processing?:

[image]

Instead of this?:

[image]

Comment: I believe the answer is because the old screens and TV's, were "drawing" pixels using the [raster scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_scan) technique. So electrones were fired starting from the [top left corner](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/72/Raster-scan.svg/450px-Raster-scan.svg.png), similarily to how people write on piece of paper.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I came across another answer, which matches yours: "[The origin placement] might seem weird at first, but if you think about an image as a matrix, it makes sense that the "00" element is in the upper left." (Udacity's self-driving car course) Feel free to make your comment the answer so I can accept.

Comment: It is more common in IT to describe images with the origin in the top-left corner, than the mathematical coordinates system. Some formats don't do it, but the majority does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose that the raster scan is a Western invention, in analogy with the way we write: left to right, top to bottom. Remember that "rastrum" denotes a  rake. When you rake a surface, or paint a floor, one usually does this such that one does not step on the raked or painted surface. The "raker" or "painter" moves backwards. One wants to avoid the situation described in [Painted Into A Corner](https://www.cartoonstock.com/directory/p/painted_into_a_corner.asp):

[image: Painted Into A Corner]

This defines a sort of 2D causality, using data for above and if not, from the same level (row) but left.  Parsing the 2D space top to bottom then left to right could have been an option. However, we know that the human vision is more sensitive to vertical than to horizontal, as one can see from the JPEG quantization matrix.

So perhaps, by going left to right first, the human mind could more easily spot a vertical change in a whole picture. *

However, the ancient slowness of a beam parsing a screen is not less important. For web browsing, it can be more important to first display a global low resolution patch and refine it iteratively, like in the progressive JPEG, JPEG 2000, or the clever [Adam7 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam7_algorithm) used in PNG.

See for instance http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/pngpics.html

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced both systems and I think that they depend on different conventions.

The typical left-right-top-bottom [raster scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_scan) is probably a remnant from the way the television signal was structured and [due to the way the Cathode Ray Tubes (CRT) worked.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_blanking_interval) (Which is also hinting back to the mechanical scan-disk that was used initially to convert a picture to a signal long, long, long time ago).

This convention makes sense for a number of reasons relevant to the way the human visual system works but it also makes technical sense as the vertical retrace signal can trigger shifting out a line of data to the screen and eventually whole frames.

However, in OpenGL, texture coordinates $(u,v)$ are always $u,v \in \left[0 \ldots 1\right]$ and $(0,0)$ [denotes the **bottom-left** corner](https://open.gl/textures). It is typical to create a quad plane, slap a texture on it and find it rendered upside down if you don't take care in the mapping between object coordinates $(x,y,z)$ and texture coordinates $(u,v)$. The $\left[0 \ldots 1 \right]$ interval is a headache too, especially when you are trying to pinpoint a specific boundary.

Why is it so? I do not have a reference for this but I vaguely remember this being related to the way the [Silicon Graphics (SGI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_Graphics) hardware, [where OpenGL was first developed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL#History), worked.

Hope this helps.